# Have a specific list find howmany times exist

Tags: r, string

If I have a specific list with terms like this:

```
df_specific <- data.frame(terms = c("hi", "why here", "see you soon"))
```

and a framework with text

```
df_text <- data.frame(text = c("hi my name is", "why here you are", 
                      "hi see you later", "I hope to see you soon"))
```

How is it possible to use the first list as index to find in the `df_text` how many times exist?

Example of expected output:

```
term num
hi    2
why here 1
see you soon 1
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `grepl` for an individual term and use `sapply` to map that across all of your test terms.

```
sapply(df_specific$terms, function(x) sum(grepl(x, df_text$text)))
[1] 2 1 1
```

If you want to get the specific format that you listed,  just `cbind` the previous result onto df_specific

```
num = sapply(df_specific$terms, function(x) sum(grepl(x, df_text$text)))
cbind(df_specific, num)

         terms   num
1           hi     2
2     why here     1
3 see you soon     1
```

Answer (score 2):

## Overview

Using the [tidyverse](/questions/tagged/tidyverse), I supplied each value in `df_specific$term` as the pattern to test for its existence in all the values in `df_text$text` via `map_df()` and `str_count()`.

```
# load necessary packages ----
library(tidyverse)

# load necessary data ------
df_specific <- tibble(terms = c("hi", "why here", "see you soon"))
df_text <- tibble(text = c("hi my name is"
                           , "why here you are"
                           , "hi see you later"
                           , "I hope to see you soon"))

# perform analysis --------
df_specific %>%
  pull(terms) %>%
  set_names() %>%
  # for each value in df_text$text
  # count how many times .x appears in the vector
  map_df(.f = ~ str_count(string = df_text$text
                       , pattern = .x) %>% sum()) %>%
  # transform data from wide to long
  gather(key = "term", value = "num")
# A tibble: 3 x 2
# term           num
# <chr>        <int>
# 1 hi               2
# 2 why here         1
# 3 see you soon     1

# end of script #
```